# product of consecutive prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Happy new year.

I am studying the product of  consecutive prime numbers. For the $n$-th prime number $p_n$, I denote  $\mu_{n}=p_1 p_2 \ldots p_n$.

The problem is that I can not search for the properties of $\mu_{n}$.

Thus, I'd like to know some properties about the $\mu_{n}$. It does not have to have detail. I wonder just name of theorem or related some paper.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Cf. [primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial), denoted $p_n\#$

Comment: Oh! really thank for help. Happy new year!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The product of the first $n$ primes is called primorial and denoted $p_n\#$.

You can read more about them on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial) or [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Primorial.html).

Comment: Thanks! It is enough. I'd like to close the question.

Comment: @Giyuob Don't close the question. Leave it up for others to use.

Comment: @Giyuob:  thank you for accepting my answer; best wishes

Comment: Okay! I'll leave it. I'm sorry, I did't know mean that closing.